# Dimension of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ without cardinality argument.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, irrational-numbers, real-numbers

I am looking for the easiest (elementary) proof that $\mathbb R$ is infinite dimensional as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, without using cardinality. It should be understandable at highschool level.

So I guess the question could be reformulated as: what is the easiest infinite family of reals that can be showed to be independent ? So far square roots of primes seems a good candidate, but the proof is still a little intricate, is it the easiest possible ?

The goal of this is to show students that we can prove the result by different ways, and see that understanding cardinals is useful. But I still want the students to be able to understand the other proof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the set:

$$\{\log p\}_p$$

of logs of prime numbers. They are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic--i.e. unique factorization of integers greater than $1$ into primes. As there are infinitely many primes, the set $\Bbb R$ contains an infinite dimensional subspace, and is so itself infinite dimensional. (This is the standard proof number theorists love).

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for, thanks ! It is almost better than the cardinality proof...

Comment: Glad to help! As a number theorist I love this kind of thing. :-)

Comment: in a strict sense you need FTA, because some of the $a_p$ can be negative, and then you have to say that the decomposition is unique.

Comment: I like recycling this fact **a lot** in algebra it takes the form of presenting $\Bbb Q$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module of the form:

$$\Bbb Q\cong \bigoplus_p \Bbb Z$$

where the index represents the exponent of the prime.

Answer (score 8):

Try $\{1, \pi, \pi^2, \pi^3,\ldots\}$ (or use any transcendental number instead of $\pi$). Since if $$\sum_{i=0}^na_i\pi^i=0, \text{  }a_i\in\mathbb Q$$then $\pi$ must be a root of $$a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_nx^n$$which would contradict the transcendence of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks it is nice, but transcendance of $\pi$ is a hard result which must be admitted at this level... It is harder than the proof with square root of primes.

Comment: It would work with any transcendental number. Are there any that you could prove a result for?

Comment: The only argument I know for existence of transcendental numbers is cardinality ;)

Comment: I see the issue... there is Liouville's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence) but that is hardly high school level. I'll have a think

Comment: Transcendence of $e$ is [more easily proven](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m400su06/transcendence%20of%20e.pdf) than for $\pi$.